# Getting a Different Sort Order Between "SPSS sort cases by" and Python "sort_values(by=[])

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, spss

I am attempting to convert some code from SPSS into Python. In the code, the SPSS "sort cases by" command is resulting in a different sorted order than the Pandas "df.sort_values(by=[]) command. For reference, here is the code in the two programs:

SPSS

```
GET FILE='C:\Data\sorttest.sav'.
sort cases by variable1.
dataset name sorttest.
execute.
```

Python

```
import pandas as pd
df_sorttest = pd.read_spss('C:\\Data\\sorttest.sav')
df_sorttest = df_sorttest.sort_values(by=['variable1'])
```

I assume this is because they are using different sorting algorithms, but I'm not sure how to fix it so I can get the same results in Python.

Comment: You can specify the sort algorithm you want you use in [sort_values](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html)

Comment: Do you happen to know which algorithm SPSS uses by default to match it? EDIT: I think I got it, I used kind='mergesort' and got the same order. Thank you!

Comment: I do not but I would first check that the data type for the column you want to sort is correct: for example, `'123'` as a str will sort differently than `123` as an int.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to It_is_Chris for the recommendation to specify the algorithm. I set it to kind='mergesort' and it got the correct order.